# Heroku IP address "not pinging" according to 1&1?

Tags: heroku, dns, ping, cname

I've created an app on Cedar with Heroku..... and want my 1&1 domain to point to it.

I've followed this instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#ip-addresses), and added the domain to Heroku - which appears correctly in the app settings.

At the 1&1 end, I've added the appropriate CNAME in the name server settings as mydomain.herokuapp.com, and it now shows as 'ready', and it's there when I check the DNS status.

However, after 48 hours, it still hasn't switched. According to a guy I spoke to on the phone at 1&1, this is because "the CNAME url isn't pinging". I'm afraid this is beyond my technical knowledge, and I don't know if this means I have done something wrong.

I'd be v grateful if anyone could help, or has had the same problem. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The Heroku endpoints don't "ping" -- they filter ICMP requests. This is normal. (They do, however, respond to HTTP.) What is the domain in question?

Comment: the domain is www.redditedit.com, and the Heroku app is redditedit.herokuapp.com. Heroku have told me that "since your app was idling as it was only running a single process, it was not pingable by your DNS's systems."... so advised me to scale up with the following command: `$ heroku ps:scale web=2 -a redditedit`. 1&1 have told me it's now pinging, but need to wait another 48 hours for propagation! Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Well, this sure is more than 48 hours `(:` Please update with what happened. Thanks. I have a similar issue.

Comment: No need for a CNAME. Just produce an A record in heroku and enter it in 1&1. Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434704/11-domain-pointing-to-heroku/61887009#61887009