# 1&1 domain pointing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, redirect, cname

I am aware that there have been a few discussions on this one but none have given a definitive answer. I am hoping this will help me and others.

Problem:
 
I have a domain name (www.xyz.com) registered with 1&1. 
I want users to be able to type this in and be shown my website. A Heroku web app. 
I want the domain name (www.xyz.com) to be displayed. Not any subdomain url or the heroku app URL.
I do not want the set-up do be anything that will have a detrimental impact on SEO.

Note: 
I have just got off the phone with 1&1 and they have said that my only options are to do a frame redirect or a http forward. Neither of these meet the above requirements. 
Additionally, other posts have suggested finding out what the Heroku IP address is and using this but Heroku recommend against this as they might change it without notice.

Please could I ask that any one kind enough to respond spells things out a little. Anyone having problems with redirects is likely to be new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know that Heroku IPs could change until mine did yesterday :-( I'm using  `heroku domains:add` now and living with the fact that I have to have www in my url.

Answer (score 1):

never used the 1&1 services, but solving your problem is pretty straightforward.

Take the following steps:

1. Add you domain to heroku. `heroku domains:add www.xyz.com` . If you have more than 1 app in your heroku account, remember to pass the `--app` flag
2. Now you should have something like `myherokuapp.herokuapp.com` where myherokuapp is the name of your app on heroku
3. Go to 1&1 and create a `CNAME` record pointing to `myherokuapp.herokuapp.com`

Comment: 1&1 do not allow you to create a CNAME for your domain, only subdomains. This means that you would see the sub-domain url at the top of the page rather than your domain name. e.g. sub.xyz.com rather than www.xyz.com.

Comment: Ok so you can't insist on 1&1 anymore to attend your current needs. You need a DNS service such as the ones offered by Amazon route 53, DNS Simple, etc, which supports pointing `www.xyz.com` to your herokuapp.
They offer relative cheap services, the setup is easy and straightforward.  You only need log in you 1&1 account and set the new NAMESERVERS for `xyz.com` on 1&1 with the service of your choice, and then manage your DNS from there.

Answer (score 1):

I found this video to be helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLVBBAnrrL4

Basically, as noted by @Kevin Lawrence above, you use the 'www' subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used 1&1 but my DNS provider (dreamhost) does not allow CNAMEs on the main domain name either. It does however allow me to create a CNAME for the www subdomain which was good enough in my case.

I did this:

1. heroku domains:add www.mydomain.com
2. create a CNAME record pointing to mydomain.herokuapp.com
3. Have mydomain.com redirect to www.mydomain.com

It's not exactly what I wanted (or what you want) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to user `Namecheap.com`'s `FreeDNS` service that provides free automatic redirect for your TLD and subdomains directly to Heroku, while keeping your domain visible:

`example.com` and `www.example.com` now point to `exampleapp.herokuapp.com`

I had to have a live chat with Namecheap's support to complete the domain verification process, but they answered really fast! Love to namecheap, 1and1 is really crappy, moving my domains away soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work properly! No need for CNAME at all. Create a A record in heroku like in this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) - creating a custom room domain - provided by heroku (of course, change example.com to *your* root domain):

```
heroku domains:add example.com
```

Here, example.com is the ROOT domain. Once you get an A record, execute the following command

```
heroku domains:wait example.com
```

Now verify your domain has been provisioned:

```
heroku domains -a [your custom heroku app name]
```

And you get this:

```
=== [your custom app name] Custom Domains
Domain Name         DNS Record Type DNS Target
example.com     ALIAS or ANAME  elliptical-blueberry-1euo3460fyrtc8zdgulv0f7o.herokudns.com
```

Next, get the IPv4 IP address of `elliptical-blueberry-1euo3460fyrtc8zdgulv0f7o.herokudns.com` I got it by using a lookup service.

**Updating 1 and 1**

1. Go to 1and1.
2. Click the DNS tab for your custom domain e.g. example.com
3. Delete the existing A record
4. Create a new A record and enter in the @ symbol if it asks you, or else I think it is the default AND enter in the IPv4 address
5. For testing this out, make the TTL 1 min until it's stable
6. Give it time to propagate. Could be a few minutes to 24 hours.

Comment: I am afraid this would NOT work, as mentioned in Heroku's documentation : "Unfortunately, A records will not suffice for pointing your root domains to Heroku because they require a static IP. These records have serious availability implications when used in environments such as on-premise data-centers, cloud infrastructure services, and platforms like Heroku. Since Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, it’s necessary to use a CNAME-like record (often referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records) so that you can point your root domain to another domain."